# NSString hasPrefix: function with case sensitivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Simple and may asked many time but little trick with this. We know, NSString doesn't work with case sensitivity for hasPrefix: method.

```
NSString *string = @"Xyzabcdedfghij";
    NSString *substring = @"xyz";
    if ([string hasPrefix:substring])
        NSLog(@"string has prefix "); // won't get here.
```

`Question is:` **Is there any built-in method for resolve this issue? I mean, `hasPrefix:` with case sensitive?**

I could use below answer at least case. But want to know if there is any method which better than this..?

**Known answer:**(lease case)

```
if ([[test substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,3)] caseInsensitiveCompare:@"xyz"] == NSOrderedSame) {
     // ....
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html) themselves:

```
NSString *searchString = @"age";

NSString *beginsTest = @"Agencies";
NSRange prefixRange = [beginsTest rangeOfString:searchString
    options:(NSAnchoredSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch)];

// prefixRange = {0, 3}

NSString *endsTest = @"BRICOLAGE";
NSRange suffixRange = [endsTest rangeOfString:searchString
    options:(NSAnchoredSearch | NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSBackwardsSearch)];

// suffixRange = {6, 3}
```

This could be wrapped into an easy-to-use method:

```
- (BOOL) string:(NSString *)string
      hasPrefix:(NSString *)prefix
caseInsensitive:(BOOL)caseInsensitive {

    if (!caseInsensitive)
        return [string hasPrefix:prefix];

    const NSStringCompareOptions options = NSAnchoredSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch;
    NSRange prefixRange = [string rangeOfString:prefix
                                        options:options];
    return prefixRange.location == 0 && prefixRange.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: If any other way to do this, I'll follow you. But still I'm searching, any other way to do this... any way +1 for which will help future visitors :)

Comment: @iMani Other than the alternative you show in your question and the answer from Volker, then I doubt there are many more alternatives.

Comment: Ya I'm also waiting for that. If some other way to do it easily without pain of range calculation.

Comment: @iMani I have updated my answer with a method you could add, which means you don't need to deal with ranges and you can just forget about them.

Comment: why is this better than [[string lowercaseString] hasPrefix:[substring lowercaseString]] ? Is it at least faster?

Answer (score 29):

You can always use `lowercaseString` on both strings and thus forcing the same case. So for example

```
[[string lowercaseString] hasPrefix:[substring lowercaseString]];
```

Comment: It will work. But I don't want to modify any strings. thanks Volker.. +1 for you :)

Comment: Thanks. the answer by @trojanfoe may be more suitable since you can choose different options for finding substrings.

Comment: This answer does **not** modify any strings.

Answer (score 9):

Nasty way to do is to lower case the both string and than use hasPrefix 
e.g.

```
[[mainString lowercaseString] hasPrefix:[stringToFind lowercaseString]];
```

Comment: How is this different than Volker's answer?

Comment: @Amar: this answer was posted a mere 1 min and 44 seconds after Volker's answer. In all likelihood they were typing them at the same time. That doesn't make their answer any less valid.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 5:

```
extension String {
    public func hasPrefixIgnoringCase(_ prefix: String) -> Bool {
        range(of: prefix, options: [.anchored, .caseInsensitive]) != nil
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
"Hello".hasPrefixIgnoringCase("hEl") // return true
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do this by

```
if([[string lowercaseString] hasPrefix:[substring lowercaseString]])
{
NSLog(@"found");
}
```

Comment: only in the above example it will work this way. A stable version needs `lowercaseString` for both strings!

Answer (score 3):

A Swift 4.2 version of accepted answer:

```
extension String {

    public func hasPrefix<Prefix>(_ prefix: Prefix, caseSensitive: Bool) -> Bool where Prefix : StringProtocol {

        if caseSensitive { return self.hasPrefix(prefix) }

        let prefixRange = self.range(of: prefix, options: [.anchored, .caseInsensitive])
        return prefixRange != nil
    }
}
```

Alternatively, using `.lowercased()`

```
extension String {

    public func hasPrefix<Prefix>(_ prefix: Prefix, caseSensitive: Bool) -> Bool where Prefix : StringProtocol {

        if caseSensitive { return self.hasPrefix(prefix) }
        return self.lowercased().hasPrefix(prefix.lowercased())
    }
}
```

The extension is to use as following

```
let string = "Hello World"

let caseSensitiveSearch = string.hasPrefix("hello", caseSensitive: true) // return false
let caseNotSensitiveSearch = string.hasPrefix("hello", caseSensitive: false) // return true
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who like functional style one-liners (like I do):

```
extension String {

    func hasPrefix<Prefix>(_ prefix: Prefix, caseSensitive: Bool) -> Bool where Prefix: StringProtocol {
        return caseSensitive ? hasPrefix(prefix) :
            self.range(of: prefix, options: [.anchored, .caseInsensitive]) != nil
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
extension StringProtocol {
    public func hasPrefix<T: StringProtocol>(caseInsensitive prefix: T) -> Bool {
        lowercased().starts(with: prefix.lowercased())
    }
}
```

Use:

```
"Hello World".hasPrefix(caseInsensitive: "hello") //true
```